# Is there a way to force Jetty to only use HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, https, jetty

I'm trying to force Jetty to only use HTTPS (or redirect to HTTPS from HTTP).

So far, I can access the server using both HTTP and HTTPS.

Here's the connector configuration:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8888"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
        <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
        <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
        <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">1000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">500</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>

   <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector">
        <Set name="Port">8443</Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
        <Set name="handshakeTimeout">2000</Set>
        <Set name="keystore"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/keystore</Set>
        <Set name="password">aaa</Set>
        <Set name="keyPassword">bbb</Set>
        <Set name="truststore"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/keystore</Set>
        <Set name="trustPassword">aaa</Set>
        <Set name="handshakeTimeout">2000</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
```

I've tried setting the default port as 8443 (in the first connector), that didn't work and generated an error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the first `<Call name="addConnector">` section, that's the one that adds the plain HTTP connector (`org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector`).

Comment: Thank you sir for making me feel like a noob! :)

Comment: For people trying to do the same thing with Jetty 9.1, simply remove the file called `start.d/http.ini` (the one that contains `--module=http`).

Comment: Good grief! This information was so hard to find. Thanks, Bruno!

Comment: I got a bunch of errors when I simply deleted the file. so I just commented it out instead which worked nicer.